# MySQL: How to use CASE for ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that must return a table after filtering rows based on inputs. Two of the inputs are `sort_column` and `sort_dir`. The query must ORDER BY `sort_column` in the `sort_dir` direction(ASC or DESC).

I have tried the following queries but in vain. The queries below have been simplified to only contain the relevant clauses. The other filters work correctly with no issues.

1. `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sort_column sort_dir`
2. `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE sort_column
                 WHEN 'col1' THEN col1_name 
                 WHEN 'col2' THEN col2_name END 
                 CASE sort_dir WHEN 'asc' THEN ASC
                     ELSE DESC END`
3. I concatenated the 2 inputs to 1 in the format _ and tried this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE sort_input
     WHEN 'col1_asc' THEN col1_name ASC
     WHEN 'col1_desc' THEN col1_name DESC
     WHEN 'col2_asc' THEN col2_name ASC
     WHEN 'col2_desc' THEN col2_name DESC END
   ```

I always get error #1064. It is different in each of the above cases but always points to the 'CASE' part. This is the error for option number 2 mentioned above

> **##1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN 'col1' THEN col1_name END CASE 'asc' WHEN 'desc' THEN DESC ELSE ' at line 4**

The problem doesn't seem to be the column name. It is the sort direction that isn't working. If I try each of the above options without the 'ASC' and 'DESC' parts, there is no problem.

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Is there a better way to go about this apart from CASE?

MySQL version: 5.6

Comment: Please add the complate error message, not only a part

Comment: What's wrong with simply `ORDER BY sort_column sort_dir`? You shouldn't need any CASE statement. But it would take the complete error message (the "near .... " part) to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @Jens I have edited the question to contain the full error message. Please check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Thilo I have edited the question to include the full error message. When I use the first option, it doesn't sort at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach is multiple `cases`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sort_input = 'col1_asc' THEN col1_name END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN sort_input = 'col1_desc' THEN col1_name END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN sort_input = 'col2_asc' THEN col2_name END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN sort_input = 'col2_desc' THEN col2_name END) DESC,
```

This may seem verbose.  But, remember that `CASE` is an expression that returns a single value.  Hence you cannot include `ASC` and `DESC` as part of the `THEN`.

Also important is the issue of data types.  The SQL compiler decides on a single type for `CASE` expression.  This can cause unexpected issues when the columns have different types.

The simplest solution is just to use multiple `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I'm curious, when the rest 3 CASE statements evaluate to false and aren't executed, wouldn't the query end up like `ORDER BY ASC, DESC, col2_name ASC, DESC`? (This is for when `sort_input` is "col2_asc".

Comment: Also, how do you think I can add a default column to sort by?

Comment: @javaGirl243 . . . You would add it as the final key.  `order by (case . . .), (case . . .), . . ., defaultcol`.  Also, the `case` expressions return `NULL`, not no value at all, so the syntax is fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  IMO you should only use multiple cases when you have multiple sorting orders otherwise single case can happily cover up multiple statements.

Comment: Does this mean that it will only sort and order only on one matching case condition?